# SQL запрос с использованием 'NULL'

Tags: sql

Читаю книгу - "SQL для простых смертных" - в конце каждой главы задание - написать короткие запросы, так вот, написал запрос к задаче:

5.5. "Запишите запрос, который выбирает все заявки, у которых в поле amt (amount) указано значение О или NULL.
Собственно запрос:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Orders
 WHERE amt IN (0, 'NULL');
```

Правильный запрос:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Orders
 WHERE amt < > 0
   AND (amt IS NOT NULL);
```

Вопрос - почему не поддерживается такой тип запроса( если можно с разъяснениями про типы данных)

Comment: Спасибо, да я помню что в тексте было такое. Перечитаю.

Comment: 'NULL' - это строковый литерал. это уже - ошибка. Т.к. 'NULL' <> NULL. len('NULL') = 4, а len(NULL) = NULL. NULL - это больше чем значение, это состояние. При попытке обьеденить NULL в список in - NULL выпадет из списка. Т.е. `(0,NULL)` еквивалентно `(0)` а значит безсмысленно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все дело в троичной логике. `null != null  => false` и `null = null => false`. По этому для проверки на `null` используется конструкция `is null`